# ActiveAdmin resource with belongs_to: how to specify has_one rather than has_many?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, associations, activeadmin

In my app I have these three models: Account, Job, Worker. Account has a polymorphic association to both Job and Worker described as follows in `account.rb`:

```
class Account
  belongs_to :owner, polymorphic: true
end
```

Job and Worker both have `has_one :account, as: :owner`.

In Active Admin I am currently trying to set up these associations with my registered Job, Worker, and Account resources. I just registered the Account resource and added this to `/admin/account.rb`:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Account do
  belongs_to :job, :polymorphic => true, :parent_class => Job
end
```

I'm not sure if this is the correct way to start setting up the polymorphic association in Active Admin, but the other problem has to do with the way the routes are being generated by `belongs_to` here. AA is assuming that the parent class `has_many` accounts rather than `has_one` Account, so the routes are wrong. But in the AA docs I don't see a way to specify that the parent class `has_one` instead of `has_many`.

Is there a way to do this without writing the routes myself?